# Pass GET variables and go to jQuery tab

Tags: php, jquery, tabs, get

I have a jQuery tabs set up on a page on my website. I want to reference one of the tabs using a URL which I can do using:

```
http://url.com/tabs#my-tab
```

However, I also want to pass a few php variables to this page THROUGH the url as well. I have tried with minimal success by doing this:

```
http://url.com/tabs?var1=foo&var2=bar#my-tab
```

however this only seems to pass the first variable, the second one is ignored (it does go to the tab). I cannot find a way to send several variables and go to the tab. Can someone please help
Thanks

Comment: Both of those variables should be getting passed to `$_GET`, what is your PHP code?

Comment: my php code is lost in the abyss, but when I do http://url.com/tabs?var1=foo&var2=bar both variables are passed to $_GET

Comment: Right.. I think I'm misunderstanding then. So what is failing to retrieve both parameters? Is it your JavaScript trying to read the url parameters?

Comment: I have found a "hack", maybe you'll understand because I don't. When I add a third random variable, the first 2 are received and the 3rd is not. It seems that the last variable before the # is ignored... I believe we DO use a javascript function to get the vars from the URL

Comment: @Pudge601, yeah, that's what he wants, for jQuery to retrieve the variables from the URL.

Comment: If you can't show any code, we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: As Barmar says, we need to see the code. It is likely to be an issue with the way your javascript code is parsing the url to find the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I would guess that whatever method you're using to parse those GET variables isn't working. Try this method instead. First, do the following:

```
// Store the query string variables into an object.
window.getVars = {};
(function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    while (match = search.exec(query))
       window.getVars[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

Then, you should be able to access any of your GET variables as `window.getVars.var1`, `window.getVars.var2`, etc.